# How can I dismiss all Chrome notifications with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, notifications

Does Chrome have a keyboard shortcut - or the ability to bind one - that lets me dismiss notifications?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently there is no keyboard shortcut or ability to create one to dismiss notifications in chrome. If you don't want it at all you can disable completely it in **Settings**->**Content Settings**->**Notifications**.

Answer (score 2):

You can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to show your notifications dashboard, then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> in quick succession to dismiss all of your notifications quickly.

Comment: On all platforms?

Answer (score 1):

**2021 Answer**

Yes!

1. <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> = show notifications
2. <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> = select "clear all" button
3. <kbd>enter</kbd> / <kbd>spacebar</kbd> = clear all
4. <kbd>esc</kbd> = close notifications

Comment: Note:  The <shift>+<alt>+n appears to only work if you are running native chromebook apps (e.g. browser, calculator, etc.), but doesn't work if you are in a linux app (because it is sandboxed in the linux environment).  Therefore, you may have to <alt>+<tab> to a chrome app before running the steps in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here didn't work for me on windows 10 Chrome 116.0.5845.111

My solution is to tap windows key, type "Notifications" to go to the "Notifications & Action Settings" result, then down in the list of enabled applications turn chrome Off then On again. This seems to clear all the cards they have queued up.